# php: why shell_exec output curl?

Tags: php

I want to get the ouput of a curl result

I tried that:

```
$cmd = "curl $link";
$output = shell_exec($cmd); // ouput the curl !
echo $output; // EMPTY
```

I tried even

```
$cmd = "curl $link";
ob_start();
$output = shell_exec($cmd); // ouput the curl !!! why ?
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output; //EMPTY !
```

Comment: And what about a proper curl request and response?

Comment: First code works for me. macOS 10.12, PHP 7.0.11